Filepond - how to add button to each image preview overlay
Using Filepond / Svelte 5, I'm trying to add a custom button to each added image on the image preview overlay. When the button is clicked, it will add the image to every Filepond component within the given form. Is this possible?
A simplified version of my Filepond component:
<div class="w-full mx-auto -mt-2">
    <div class="form-control">
        <label class="label form-label" for="images">Images</label>
        <FilePond
            bind:this={pond}
            id="images"
            name="files"
            server={serverConfig}
            allowRevert={true}
            allowMultiple={true}
            allowReorder={true}
            chunkUploads={true}
            chunkSize={5000000}
            maxFiles={3}
            class="w-full"
            imagePreviewHeight="200rem"
            labelIdle="<span>Drag & Drop your images or </span><span class='filepond--label-action'>Browse</span>"
        />
    </div>
</div>


Where is FilePond from/what is its code?

the Filepond component is from the 'svelte/filepond' library. As shown here: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/getting-started/installation/svelte/
